# Configuring an ECharts themeRiver type chart

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts

I am having trouble with some advanced configuration of an ECharts themeRiver chart.

You can see my implementation [here](https://data.geo-kima.org/Places/Details?id=550), and a codepen is attached below.

Here are my questions:

1. How can I remove the legends that are are all bunched up on the left (because all initial values are 0 or small)?
2. How can I increase the number of ticks (interval:0 seems to not have an effect).
3. How can i format the number shown at the top of the axis tooltip (the year) so it has no decimal fraction and not thousands separator (same as I managed to do for the axis tick marks)?
4. How can i apply the Decal Patern option shown in the [demo](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=themeRiver-basic)?

Thanks you!

echarts option object(codepen [here](https://codepen.io/GilShalit/pen/vYQvNZp). The Data objects are abbreviated here but available in codepen):

```
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'line',
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
        width: 5,
        type: 'solid'
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    data: [...]
  },
  singleAxis: {
    min: 1606,
    max: 2011,
    top: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    axisTick: {interval: 50},
    axisLabel: {
       formatter: function (value) {
            return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "");
        }
    },
    type: 'value',
    axisPointer: {
        animation: true,
        label: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    splitLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
            type: 'dashed',
            opacity: 0.2
        }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'themeRiver',
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {
          shadowBlur: 20,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
        }
      },
      data: [...]
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [labels](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-themeRiver.label.show) can be disabled via:

```js
series: [
   {
      label: {show: false}
   }
]
```

2. set [maximum gap](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#singleAxis.maxInterval) between axis labels via:

```js
singleAxis: {
    maxInterval: 50,
}
```

3. tooltip can be formatted via [tooltip formatter](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.formatter). I currently didnt manage to get line breaks into it but this is quite close:

```js
tooltip: {
    formatter: function(values) {
        const year = parseInt(values[0].data[0]);
        return year.toFixed() + "\n" + values.map(value => value.data[1] + " " + value.data[2]).join("\n");
    }
}
```

4. [decal pattern](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#aria.decal) can be activated via:

```js
myChart.setOption({
    aria: {
        enabled: true,
        decal: {show: true}
    }
})
```

Here is the adjusted [Demo](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=doc-example%2Ftext-block-fragment&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULWBDAThLAXMuppgKbRYBGANmQCZFg4CuZANCafWQMZY0iSAM4ALYAHcmrMgF9OGWPK5hgwGpBBCumAGbAcAWyxgwZHEV0tovSDAAUANwFthASmKLSsXjGFhYAE8yXARYEFxhMgBJaDAnFzJhAG0ABgBdADp6Eyw09LcAbh1SHDIwFhw4YNxM1QAxCAAPBnsPAGpYACIAHWgu2E7nGldM4xAEkbIEAD5YYbZs3OSARnTB7s2hxKWwPIAmAsyAK2AIaHte_qKS5S9YZggAcyfzIgByLCaIYXeFby-PwACmc4m9PN5MGBAiAyB8aOcyH8SpgEdAyABlaF0bT3by-GgGD44J5ULD2VLsSnUzL7NzIvGkCQQehgUREACs_0hUJhcNg72E6hZ7xRSluXDuqLIr2gjAh3FyRGSXUAC6CAPdBAJeggA3QQAXoIBl0EAu6Bddhq9WAQ9A9UaTWadYBN0ANxtNGvtgB3QR02l3ah361VOs2WwBHoAa_Z6tVbQ87w3b3b7_V7g3Gw5aQ8b0pLucJzk86ABBb7CXHeQznIgrABsqXL3MwxiaRH2qRWKxrD1AnMpJSowFMwEMHdbddiZhwwwHJUBwgAMtQyIIFZD9EYTCPLNZbFA4JM2B5UIyeWUKlV5jtVFi8NAnm1ivvxfcpaRobCPgska3JyDzquF5CsNAIMYdjQNIbCtt4NCzvOe48jyYiSCBZBipgsi3K2wggAiYBToiRYwXBUgPDIYGkGimLYvy0Ewd4T78u8ORiAwDJUd4oBYLwEDQkQqS0khd7eChigPlEeBJMqJSUdRfIfGyZCGGQABKECOOYTGQrJICiFgWaFj-3gcbJWKBDiumQmIWD0JIABCIwWLAjbEd4ZkWRIADC6hEgKJJkhS7CwJSfm-dxAAc9K8QJPIPuBkFCPhlgCFEkWKnsyrJO8Fb7OWfywNWApeo67zpOwqUVuW5aZByWUcjl7x5UaBVFWlADsqSNVl6W-TV4b5YVxWNQALI15VtUFLa5V1dU9U1QVBW1Kz7B1tWGvVxVBfsQVDb5ACcjULeNS2TSsQXlptWX7FyY06t1DUrJtqSbRtsArAAzLtl0Tddm0cqklWvVa-0fbdD3nZ1b3_cV5YZVl_mdSm73g6VD2jTDf3LU1LWnbtsNg01A0PdVGpY6jKyNdNWUvWNhMHat60Vb5T1BZjKNU8dlU7RTTMfXdeOM1dxWfd9vl9TzcNpZtgO03ZwvY-lmV079PrS6VZUSwzF3erzaOtb5SNegrRP9YNEvQ7rGvE6TgXy6b1MPcb0ZWyzFtq3rB23fdRuWyLN1fVDHvS2L3Hu07psQ7LAVO7GisIxLwO6xH-vo4L8txwdBs20npskzNjsg96yfXdbgc5zG9sndnsem67afhxX3tl9Ged8-LPvV57IdZULQdxkTSsPR3RepvHWuPR7fr67jhcm13Kfm2H_dT_na1V3Po_M6Xs-TyvnNu83y9-7X692_PjcBzvG-K5DddBgPB09xPFraomm-9QnB9X0fOOG6f9-P9Lmdf2_T80oFzJozH-RMjpr1tgAv2XM77QKJvzf-D9r4AxPpfZB78ZZtV-ig-Gysv5vUAcTF-OtxpENTnfQhv8Z6kKoeAxelCIzSwgQQphCDYGsNwaLfets6EuybnXPh1027a3Tpg2-rDi6YOakPWhucuHE3HpI2M5CZ68PkZg4BgiNFEJYdoqRRDK6MIMXvAWB83QKP9kvcu4iL7mIwUQiR2iwEpxfuolx10KGsI8b1NRv0fFAIYdgtWATDoO3saEoxwSc6RJ4f4yxAiIkKJEa_NhN8o5IIUTIzJ0ilHoKyX49mCitHDyKZo8JUC0lb2sffSxcSymGMSaQ2GK90z3i4G02QhQgA).

Comment: This is great! I will try to improve on the tooltip formatter to get the line break in. And strangely, the decal is not showing.  Could I be missing something in the custom download?

Comment: Did you look at the demo I linked? Are you setting decal in the same way? Maybe its a version issue? import issue? typo?

Comment: I did look at your demo. And it works in my demo too. But I can't make it work in my code - I tried to create a full download with all options, and to remove jquery and bootstrap js and css includes - still no luck. Ah well, it's only nice to have... Thanks again.

Comment: for completeness here is a tooltip formatter that works: return "<div>" + year.toFixed() + "</div>" + values.map(value => "<div>" + value.data[2] + " " + value.data[1] + "</div>").toString().replaceAll(",", "");